# How do you set Discord bot's playing status uptime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to set bot's custom playing uptime? For example: Playing {game} for 50 minutes, and add +1 to it every minute.

I tried searching the entire web, but I couldn't find anything similar to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` to set a new presence every minute.

```js
let time = 0; // Time in minutes

setInterval(async () => {
  time += 1; // Add one minute to the above defined variable
  await client.user.setPresence({
    game: {
      name: `Gamename for ${time} minutes`,
      type: 0
    }
  });
}, 60000);
```